# Откуда производится динамический импорт после компиляции python в exe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, импорт, python-import

Есть программа на python, которая активно использует динамический импорт `__import__`. Всё работает и работает хорошо.

Но после сборки в `exe` через `pyintaller` `__import__` начинает вести себя не вполне адекватно. Скажем так, мне самому не очень понятно, как `__import__` должен вести себя в собранном проекте.. Как он вообще должен себя вести? Он должен импортировать из текущей рабочей директории, из внутренних ресурсов `exe` или как?

Я пытался и так, и так. Всё безуспешно. После сборки всё ломается, файлы-модули, конечно, не находятся.

Отказываться от динамического импорта не хотелось бы, ведь нужно постоянно реализовывать новые команды, расширения основной программы.

Comment: В принципе импорт работает точно также как и всегда. А pyinstaller-у надо явно показать какие модули нужно включить в бандл, если он не сообразил сам, через hiddenimports в spec файле.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Спасибо. Если ему указать hiddenimports в spec то он, получается, включит это дело в exe... А можно его как-то заставить импортировать модуль из внешней среды, например, импортировать D:\Modules\doit.py, будто бы этот doit.py является частью проекта?